# dBWriteTable cannot write NULLs into SQL Server table for date fields

Tags: r, sql-server

I cannot insert NULL (NA) values into an SQL Server **Date** column field using dbWriteTable.

```
dbWriteTable(con, "BIOutput", data[Cdate == date,], append = TRUE);
```

I get the error:

```
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 22007: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] 
[SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from 
character string.
```

I understand this works for numeric fields, but why doesn't it work for Dates? What workaround can I use?